# Adding html elements from variable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am trying to add elements to specific div, but not using clone(), because i need fresh copy of original elements on every add, mainly because elements are draggable and their values are being change by user? So i have my html in variable, i need to take this elements and add them on click to another elem. ?

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

var $gElem = $(
    '<div class="distributionWrapper" id="element_0">' +
        '<div class="cbox cboxQuarterWidth">'  +         
            '<select id="combobox100">'+
                '<option>1</option>'+
                '<option>2</option>'+
            '</select>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="help"><a href="javascript:;"></a></div>'+
        '<div class="cbox cboxEighthWidth"><span>'+
            '<select id="combobox200" name="PeriodId">'+
                '<option>1</option>'+
                '<option>2</option>'+
            '</select>'+
        '</span></div>'+
        '<div class="clear" id="clearDistribution"><a href="javascript:;"></a></div>'+
        '<div class="add" id="addDistribution"><a href="javascript:;"></a></div>'+
    '</div>'
);

    $('.mainSearch').html($gElem); // initial load of element
    $("#combobox100").combobox();
    $("#combobox200").combobox();

var counter = 1;
$('.add').live('click', function () {
    if ($('.distributionWrapper').length === 6) return;
    //var el = $('.distributionWrapper:first').clone().attr('id', 'element_' + ++counter).appendTo('.mainSearch');
    $('.mainSearch').add($gElem).attr('id', 'element_' + ++counter);
     // here on click add gElem to .mainSearch and set atribute to .distributionWrapper

});

$('.clear').live('click', function () {
    if ($('.distributionWrapper').length === 1) return;
    $(this).parents('.distributionWrapper').remove();
});

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why dont't you change the id in id="element_0" every time you add one new, in this way every layer would have a different id

Comment: You **have** to change the ID as it must be unique to keep the html valid.

Comment: @netadictos , i need some kine of differentiation to pull values from <select>...

Comment: @DidierGhys , offcourse, for now i am changin only wrapper id, but will change all ids inside dinamicaly...

Comment: @netadictos ,DidierGhys, main goal is to multiply var gElem on click, but not with clone(), i need fresh copy with values set to default on every add!

Comment: @Ingol, why not a simple jquery append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('.mainSearch').append($gElem);
$('.mainSearch').children('.distributionWrapper:last').attr('id', 'element_' + ++counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the html as a string in a javascript variable and create a jQuery element every time you need one from that string.

```
var elemHtml = 
'<div class="distributionWrapper" id="element_0">' +
    '<div class="cbox cboxQuarterWidth">'  +         
        '<select id="combobox100">'+
            '<option>1</option>'+
            '<option>2</option>'+
        '</select>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="help"><a href="javascript:;"></a></div>'+
    '<div class="cbox cboxEighthWidth"><span>'+
        '<select id="combobox200" name="PeriodId">'+
            '<option>1</option>'+
            '<option>2</option>'+
        '</select>'+
    '</span></div>'+
    '<div class="clear" id="clearDistribution"><a href="javascript:;"></a></div>'+
    '<div class="add" id="addDistribution"><a href="javascript:;"></a></div>'+
'</div>'

$(function(){
    //your initial element
    var $elem1 = $(elemHtml);
}

function someHandler(){
    //you can create fresh new elements anywhere without cloning
    var $elem2 = $(elemHtml);
}
```

**The duplicate IDs need to be removed.** But that's outside the scope of your question.

Comment: how to store string in muplitle lines?

Comment: Like you have it above, updated example with your html even though you really need to remove the duplicate ids.

Comment: var $elem = $(elemHtml); will give you a new element and you can choose what to do whatever you want with it. You might want to read up on jQuery's .click binder http://api.jquery.com/click/